# VGG 16 model training with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use VGG16 from keras to train a model for image detection.

Based on these articles (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/06/03/fine-tuning-with-keras-and-deep-learning/ and https://learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-fine-tuning-using-pre-trained-models/), I've put some addition Dense layer to the VGG 16 model. However, the training accuracy with 20 epoche is around 35% to 41% which doesn't match the result of these articles (above 90%).

Due to this, I would like to know, did I do something wrong with my code below.

Basic setting

```
url='/content/drive/My Drive/fer2013.csv'
batch_size = 64
img_width,img_height = 48,48

# 0=Angry, 1=Disgust, 2=Fear, 3=Happy, 4=Sad, 5=Surprise, 6=Neutral
num_classes = 7 
model_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Af/cnn.h5'

df=pd.read_csv(url)  

def _load_fer():
    # Load training and eval data
    df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=',')
    train_df = df[df['Usage'] == 'Training']
    eval_df = df[df['Usage'] == 'PublicTest']
    return train_df, eval_df

def _preprocess_fer(df,label_col='emotion',feature_col='pixels'):
    labels, features = df.loc[:, label_col].values.astype(np.int32), [
        np.fromstring(image, np.float32, sep=' ')
        for image in df.loc[:, feature_col].values]
    
    labels = [to_categorical(l, num_classes=num_classes) for l in labels]

    features = np.stack((features,) * 3, axis=-1)
    features /= 255
    features = features.reshape(features.shape[0], img_width, img_height,3)
    return features, labels

# Load fer data
train_df, eval_df = _load_fer()

# preprocess fer data
x_train, y_train = _preprocess_fer(train_df)
x_valid, y_valid = _preprocess_fer(eval_df)

gen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = gen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size)
predict_size_train = int(np.math.ceil(len(x_train) / batch_size)) 

input_tensor = Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
```

Now comes the model training part

```
baseModel = VGG16(
    include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
    input_tensor=input_tensor
    )

# Construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the base model (fine tuning)

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = Flatten()(headModel)
headModel = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(headModel)
#headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = BatchNormalization()(headModel)
headModel = Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(headModel)

model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

for layer in baseModel.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
```

[model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs0tv.png)

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                       optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), 
                       metrics=['accuracy'])

 history = model.fit(train_generator, 
                    steps_per_epoch=predict_size_train * 1, 
                    epochs=20,
                    validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=predict_size_valid)
```

Result:
[Result after training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wucna.png)
It will be very thankful for you advice.
Best Regards.

Comment: Can you add the dataset details which model is trained on. Like size, batch_size etc.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the learning rate to say 0.0001. Sometimes 0.001 is too high.

Comment: @Frightera I've just added some details about the data.

Comment: @DwightFoster I'll try it later. But I've tried with different optimizers from keras which return quite difficult result. However, the accuracy is still below 45%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are freezing all layers, only one dense layer might not give you desired accuracy. Also if you are not in hurry, you may not set up the **validation_steps** and **steps_per_epochs** parameters. Also in [this](https://learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-fine-tuning-using-pre-trained-models/) tutorial, model is having fluctuations, which do not want.

I suggest:

```
    for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

base_out = baseModel.get_layer('block3_pool').output // layer name may be different, 
                                                       check with model baseModel.summary
```

With that you can get spefic layer's output. After got the output, you can add some convolutions. After convolutions try stacking more dense layers like:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

x = Dense(512, activation= 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(256, activation= 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

output_model = Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax')(x)
```

If you don't want to add convolutions and use baseModel completely, that's also fine however you can do something like this:

```
for layer in baseModel.layers[:12]: // 12 is random you can try different ones. Not 
                                       all layers are frozen this time.
    layer.trainable = False

for i, layer in enumerate(baseModel.layers):
       print(i, layer.name, layer.trainable)
       // check frozen layers
```

After that,  you can try to set:

```
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = Flatten()(headModel)
headModel = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(512, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(headModel)
```

If you see your model is learning, but your loss having fluctuations then you can reduce learning rate. Or you can use ReduceLROnPlateau callback:

```
rd_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor = np.sqrt(0.1), patience= 4, verbose = 1, min_lr = 5e-8)
```

Parameters are totally up to your model. For more details you can see [docs](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I upfreeze all layers of VGG 15, the training accuracy is getting quite high over 60%. How should I interpret this? Since freezing all layers of my baseModel improve accuracy not at all.

Comment: If you unfreeze all layers, the imagenet weights will be your starting point. That's also an option if you have enough data. Try discarding 3-4 layers from VGG model as I suggested. Then add your own conv layers. 2-3  conv layers should be enough.

Comment: I've freeze first ten con layers VGG model and it improves the accuracy significantly, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, if your problem is solved, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

what is the form of the content of y_train. If they are integer values then you need to convert them to one hot vectors with

```
y_train=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train, num_classes)
```

since you are using loss='categorical_crossentropy' in model.compile. In addition VGG16 requires that the pixels be scaled between -1 and +1 so in include

```
gen = ImageDataGenerator(tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input, etc
```

When you are training you have

```
for layer in baseModel.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
```

so you are only training the dense layer which is OK but may not give you high accuracy. You might want to leave VGG as trainable but of course this will take longer. Or after you train with VGG not trainable, then change it back to trainable and run a few more epochs to fine tune the model.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Based on freezing the VGG 16 part, since I make all VGG be trainable, the accuracy now gets higher. How should I interpret this? Does this mean that the original VGG 16 is not good enough and fine tuning is always necessary?

Comment: You will generally get improvement by fine tuning your model. VGG was trained on imagenet data set which I suspect is substantially different from yours so fine tuning lets the model adapt better to your specific data